# How to query data with attribute in an interval in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, nosql

I want to make request to MongoDB via Mongoose. I need in get documents in interval.

For example: I have cats with their ages:

```
[
 {
   name: "cat1",
   age: 3
 },
 {
   name: "cat2",
   age: 2
 },
 {
   name: "cat3",
   age: 5
 }
]
```

I make request to get cats from 4 to 10 ages, and I have to get:

```
[
 {
  name: "cat3",
  age: 5
 }
]
```

How to make this request in mongoose?

Comment: The [first example in the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) shows how to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$gte` (greater than) and `$lte` (less than) in mongoose query:

```
await Cat.find({ age: { $gte: 4, $lte: 10 } });
```

This is documents:

- How to query in mongoose: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html
- $gte: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/
- $lte: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/